# Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx Server stopped auth.log update for WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress, login

I can see that my Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx /1.15.12 server stopped recording WordPress site login (success and failure) records on "*var/log/auth.log*" file. This server correctly records SSH login details.

Then I added following code to "wp-config.php" but no luck.

> define('WP_SYSLOG_CRITICITY_LEVEL', 'info');

How do I identify root cause for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue is, my server installed CSF uses (*csf.conf*) `RESTRICT_SYSLOG = "3"` now I changed it to `RESTRICT_SYSLOG = "0"` now Wordpress login details records on auth.log file.